# Error when installing Gem phashion: ld: library not found for -ljpeg

Tags: ruby, rubygems, apple-m1

When I doing bundle install of my project with `Pashion` in my gemfile.

I encountered troubleshooting:
`ld: library not found for -ljpeg`.

Confirmed things are I have installed `jpeg, libjpeg, libpng` by following commands.
`brew install jpeg` and `brew install libjpeg`
`brew install libpng`

`gem install phashion -v '1.2.0'` will get the same error.

```
Machine: MacBook Air (M1, 2020)
Os: macOS BigSur 11.2 (20D64)

$ gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin20.3.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin

Related:
I use homebrew, which has full support on NEW Mac(M1), to install pacakges.
I use rvm(1.29.12) to manage ruby(2.6.3 as default).
```

Most like the problem here https://github.com/westonplatter/phashion/issues/19

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After lots of searching and tries, the solution is as follows:

0. `gem install phashion -v '1.2.0'`
   You will get troubleshooting: `ld: library not found for -ljpeg`
1. install phashion with config
   `LIBRARY_PATH=$LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/homebrew/opt/libjpeg/lib gem install phashion -v '1.2.0'`
   Then you will get troubleshooting: `fatal error: 'jpeglib.h' file not found`
2. last troubleshooting is because of clang path error. So
   Add `export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/opt/homebrew/include` into `~/.zshrc`
   Don't forget to `source ~/.zshrc`.
3. run `LIBRARY_PATH=$LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/homebrew/opt/libjpeg/lib gem install phashion -v '1.2.0'` once again.
   Then You will get troubleshooting: `ld: library not found for -lpng`
4. run `LIBRARY_PATH=$LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/homebrew/opt/libjpeg/lib:/opt/homebrew/opt/libpng/lib gem install phashion -v '1.2.0'` once again.

Installation success!

Comment: Thank you. I've just switched to M1 machine and had this problem when setting up rails. I also had to fix this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631572/rails-mysql-on-apple-silicon

Comment: M1 Pro machine here. Worked like a charm!

Comment: This worked correctly, but how do I do that when the `phashion` gem is defined in a gemfile? The env variables don't seem to work when I run Bundler.

Comment: Thanks these were the missing pieces of the puzzle for me as well (on M1 Mac).

Comment: I'm having some trouble making the `CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH` work. It doesn't seem to work for some reason and I'm still getting the `fatal error: 'jpeglib.h' file not found` even though I put it in my .zshrc and sourced it. Anyone else having this problem?